# What is the Killing form of SO(3,1)?

Tags: lie-algebras

I computed the Killing form of SO(3,1). 
Now I would like to check the correctness of the result but I could not find this Killing form in any publication. 
Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

We can find it in books on Lie algebras:

**Proposition:** The Killing form of $\mathfrak{so}(p,q)$ is
given by $B(X,Y)=(q+p−2)tr(XY)$.

A possible reference is [this book](https://books.google.at/books?id=aNkoBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=Killing+form+of+so(p,q)&source=bl&ots=FxE3j8ytj-&sig=ACfU3U15-50sbaBj9hpElePFAHZzSrqAaA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM2rGk2YbpAhUGHxoKHbm6AjUQ6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Killing%20form%20of%20so(p%2Cq)&f=false). The result can be obtained in a similar way as in in this post:

[Killing-form $\mathrm{Tr}(\mathrm{ad}_{X} \circ \mathrm{ad}_{Y})$ of $\mathfrak{so}(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196178/killing-form-mathrmtr-mathrmad-x-circ-mathrmad-y-of-mathfrak). The Killing form in these cases is always proportional to the trace form.